# How to access data from firebase Realtime database child?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Realtime Database Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OK9y.png)

My realtime database json

```
 "module1" : {
"Operating System" : {
  "pdfName" : "pdf",
  "pdfUrl" : "gs://knec-pastpapers.appspot.com/module1/OS/july2007.pdf"
}
```

}

I have a problem accessing the fields under **Operating System** and display the data in Recycler view.
This is my model class

```
public class viewModel {
public String pdfName;
public String pdfUrl;


public viewModel() {

}

public viewModel(String pdfName, String pdfUrl) {
    this.pdfName = pdfName;
    this.pdfUrl=pdfUrl;
}


public String getPdfName() {
    return pdfName;
}

public void setPdfName(String pdfName) {
    this.pdfName = pdfName;
}

public String getPdfUrl() {
    return pdfUrl;
}

public void setPdfUrl(String pdfUrl) {
    this.pdfUrl = pdfUrl;
}
```

This is how i am trying to access the fields from realtime database

```
databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ict").child("Operating System");
    getImageData();
}

private void getImageData() {
    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot di:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                viewModel articleList=di.getValue(viewModel.class);
                articleLists.add(articleList);
            }
            loadpdfsAdapter adapter=new loadpdfsAdapter(articleLists,getApplicationContext());
            rv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

After running the code my recyclerview is empty.
My question is how can i access the child nodes under Operating System?

Comment: What exactly would you like to display in a RecyclerView? As inside your "Operating System" there are only two String values.

Comment: The two Strings Inside "Operating System"

Comment: So you need `pdf` and `gs://knec-pastpapers.appspot.com/module1/OS/july2007.pdf`. It makes no sense to display the values of a single object in a RecyclerView. This view is designed to hold multiple objects.

Comment: But am able to display the two values in a recyclerview when there is no operating system option "module1" : {
  "pdfName" : "pdf",
  "pdfUrl" : "gs://knec-pastpapers.appspot.com/module1/OS/july2007.pdf"
} and display it correctly on recyclerview

Comment: My question is how can i access to two fields when they are under Operating System. Kindly assist me @AlexMamo

Comment: Then change your `databaseReference` to `databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ict").child("module1").child("Operating System");`.

Comment: @AlexMamo this is the error am now getting  " com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type ian.knec.kneckenyapastpapers.adapter.viewModel"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for (DataSnapshot di:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){` is only needed when the snapshot you get has multiple `viewModel` child nodes. But since you're loading data from `/ict/Operating System` there is only a single `viewModel` child node.

You either have to remove the loop:

```
databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ict").child("Operating System");

databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        viewModel articleList=dataSnapshot.getValue(viewModel.class);
        articleLists.add(articleList);
        ...
```

Or you can load all of `ict` and then loop over the child nodes:

```
databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ict");

databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot di:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            viewModel articleList=di.getValue(viewModel.class);
            articleLists.add(articleList);
        }
        ...
```